# Kibana server is not ready yet при поднятии ELK через docker compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

Попробовал поднять с [Git](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) ELK. Elastic при переходе на его страничку выдает:

```
{
  "name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "wJfMbNA7TT-E_iv62P97eA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.8.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "98e1271edf932a480e4262a471281f1ee295ce6b",
    "build_date" : "2023-06-26T05:16:16.196344851Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

т.е. оно поднимается, но при открытии kibana постоянно вижу Kibana server is not ready yet.
docker logs показал:

```
[2023-07-09T08:59:04.670+00:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:9200
```

Видел, что такое может быть при несовпадении версий, но оно по умолчанию забирает последнюю для каждого компонента.

Нужна только кибана, а она как раз и не работает. Не могу определить причину. С настройкой полный профан. Пытаюсь научиться.

Comment: Как вы запускаете elk? Через `docker compose`? Если да, то это что-то странное -  в `kibana.yaml` параметр `elasticsearch.hosts:` задан как `[ http://elasticsearch:9200 ]`, при правильном запуске там никак не может быть `0.0.0.0:9200`. Добавьте в вопрос лог `docker compose up`, в каком порядке там контейнеры инициализуются.

Comment: да, через compose. Вы правы, решил пересмотреть локальные файлы, проблема, действительно, была в elasticsearch.hosts. Исправил на elasticsearch, встало на место.